# DFA, best practice

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Consider the following language {A,B,C} and the following regex (A|B)+C.
I'm a little in doubt about which of my two examples is more correct. Or are they both equally correct? *e.g.,*

[image]

Is it allowed to have multiple letters on a transition in a DFA?

Sorry for the paint quality.

Comment: The two examples are equivalent. Having "multiple letters" on a transition is just shorthand for having two transitions with same start and end but different letters.

Comment: For the transition diagram to properly define a DFA, there must be a transition for each pair of states and alphabet symbols. Your examples are missing some.

Comment: @Math1000, for clarity's sake dead states (i.e., states that aren't final and which loop back to themselves with each symbol) are usually omitted on diagrams. But you are right, they should be there to complete the DFA.

Comment: His diagrams also don't indicate the initial and accepting states...

Comment: They also seem to be describing the RE $(A\mid B)^* C$, as opposed to $(A\mid B)C$.

Comment: @Math1000 the OP means $(A \mid B)^+ C$, i.e. at least one or more occurences of $A$ or $B$ followed by a $C$.

Comment: $\{A,B,C\}$ is the alphabet, not the language. Can you confirm whether the regular expression you have in mind is $(A \mid B)^+C$ or  $(A \mid B)^*C$?

Answer (score 1):

For a regular language $L$, there are an infinite number of finite automata that recognize $L$ (just take a DFA that recognizes $L$ and add another state that transitions only to itself, for instance). However, there is a unique (up to labeling) DFA with a minimum number of states, and various algorithms for state minimization. Ceteris paribus, a DFA with fewer states would be preferable, due to being easier to understand and taking less space to store.

In this case, we have the regular expression over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$
$$R=(a\mid b)^*c, $$
which recognizes the language 
$$L = \{w\in\Sigma: w \text{ has exactly one } c \text{ and } w \text{ ends with a } c\}. $$
A DFA with one state must either accept the empty language or the set of all strings over $\Sigma$, i.e. $\Sigma^*$, so our automaton must have at least two states. Your second idea is on the right track. Formally, we would describe this DFA as $M=(Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$ where $Q=\{S_1, S_2\}$ is the set of states, $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$ is the input alphabet, $\delta:Q\times\Sigma\to Q$ is the transition function, given by
$$
\delta(q, \alpha) = \begin{cases}
S_1,& q=S_1, \alpha\ne c\\
S_2,& q=S_1, \alpha = c \text{ or } q=S_2,\alpha\in\Sigma,
\end{cases}
$$
$q_0=S_1$ is the starting state, and $F=\{S_2\}$ is the set of final (or "accepting" states). Equivalently, we may define $M$ by a transition diagram:

$\hskip2in$[image]

(I used the [jFAST](http://www46.homepage.villanova.edu/timothy.m.white/) software to produce the above image.)